# How does local SSH tunnel (-L) work with no remote command (-N)?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling

I am new to SSH tunneling and I am trying to understand how `-L` works in conjunction with `-N`.

First, let me confirm my understanding of local SSH tunnel by itself:

```
ssh -L 10000:theprotectedserver.com:9042 james@thebastionhost.com
```

This will open a shell to allow me to execute commands remotely on `thebastionhost.com` from my local machine. If any such command issues a network request (to any server?) on outgoing port 10000, the request will be forwarded to `theprotectedserver.com:9042`.

Now, assuming this is correct, let's discuss adding `-N` which according to the docs:

> -N' Do not execute a remote command. This is useful for just forwarding ports (protocol version 2 only).

So this SSH session

```
ssh -N -L 10000:theprotectedserver.com:9042 james@thebastionhost.com
```

Will now cause the commands to be executed locally on my physical machine, instead of remotely on `thebastionhost.com`? But somehow, any network requests that go to port 10000 will still be routed through the `thebastionhost.com` on to `theprotectedserver.com:9042` ?

I guess this is confusing to me because of the fact the command is executed on my machine, but the network part is decoupled and gets routed to the bastion host. Can someone explain what is going on here with a little more detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `ssh -L 10000:theprotectedserver.com:9042 james@thebastionhost.com`
>
> This will open a shell to allow me to execute commands remotely on thebastionhost.com from my local machine. If any such command issues a network request (to any server?) on outgoing port 10000, the request will be forwarded to theprotectedserver.com:9042.

That's confused but mostly wrong.

In fact, this creates a secure (encrypted and authenticated) connection to `thebastionhost` *and* requests `sshd` (the server end of the connection) to run a shell *on* `thebastionhost` after which it relays anything you input on your terminal to that shell (or a program under it), and anything output by that shell (or a program under it) back to your terminal. (More exactly it creates a PTY or pseudo-terminal on `thebastionhost` and runs a shell on that PTY, and then relays input to and output from the PTY; coordination of I/O on the PTY by the shell and any other program(s) is handled *by* the PTY in the same fashion as a local terminal on `thebastionhost`.) This continues until the remote shell exits -- usually because you told it to, with `exit` or control+D or similar, but it could be due to a failure or shutdown -- or you command the local `ssh` to disconnect (standardly squiggle,period; this is rarely used) or the local process or system is killed or dies.

It *also* listens *locally* on port 10000, and if any process (call it P) on your local/client system opens that port, `ssh` requests `sshd` to open `theprotectedserver:9042` *from* `thebastionhost` and (if successful) it relays anything sent by P over the 'tunnel' to that open and anything from that open back over the tunnel to P. This allows P to talk to whatever program is located on `theprotectedserver:9042` (which could be anything) as if P was located on `thebastionhost`. Note that if you want to explicitly run P you must go to another terminal (or pseudoterminal like a window in tmux). OTOH if anyone else is logged-on to your client system, *they* can run P without your involvement or knowledge.

Both of these (your interaction with the remote shell, and P's interaction with whatever) occur concurrently and separately even though they are multiplexed over the single secure connection. In fact there can be multiple Ps each with its own connection to whatever is at `theprotectedhost:9042` as long as that accepts such multiple connections at the TCP/IP level; most though not all TCP/IP servers or service applications do so.

> `ssh -N -L 10000:theprotectedserver.com:9042 james@thebastionhost.com`

This creates the secure connection but then skips all the rest of my first paragraph: it does not run a remote shell or relay data to and from it. In fact it ignores any input you try to give it. However, if you add `&` at the end -- or (assuming POSIX job control) you type control+Z and then the command `bg` -- the `ssh` is left running in the background and you can continue to give commands to your *local* shell. However the second para *does* happen, so you might use your local shell to run a P that accesses local port 10000 and gets relayed to `theprotectedhost:9042` exactly as above except that this time you didn't need a different (local) terminal (or user).